# using python to parse a json result from eapi

Tags: python

Please excuse my lack of experience with python. I'm working with an API that communicates with a Ethernet switch. I'm having a hard time understanding how to parse the result returned by the method below. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pyeapi

node = pyeapi.connect_to('evs')
eth_48 = node.enable('show interfaces eth48 status')
print(eth_48[0])
```

Result returned:

```
{'command': 'show interfaces eth48 status', 'result': {u'interfaceStatuses': {u'Ethernet48': {u'description': u'', u'duplex': u'duplexUnknown', u'vlanInformation': {u'interfaceMode': u'
trunk', u'interfaceForwardingModel': u'bridged'}, u'bandwidth': 0, u'interfaceType': u'1000BASE-T', u'autoNegotiateActive': True, u'autoNegotigateActive': True, u'linkStatus': u'notconn
ect', u'lineProtocolStatus': u'down'}}}, 'encoding': 'json'}
```

How do I access the individual values in this result?

Comment: It seems like you already parsed the result, i.e. you have a `dict` instead of just a JSON string. Now all you have to do is access the values, e.g. `result['command']`.

Comment: eth_48['command'] I get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Debug/Projects/PySocket/demo.py", line 5, in <module>
    eth_48['command']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: It seems like the `dict` is in `eth_48[0]`, so you should use `eth_48[0]['command']` and similar, i.e. first index into the list to get the dict, then index into the dict..

Comment: that was it thanks